# Maximum entropy inverse reinforcement theorem

Tags: maxent

I'm trying to make sense of a part in [Brian Ziebart's MaxEnt theorem proof (**Theorem 6.10**)](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ebziebart/publications/thesis-bziebart.pdf#page=210) in Appendix A.3 at page 190.

The equation P(pi) = Product over all trajectories (A, S) of P_MaxEnt(A, S)^pi(A, S) seems difficult to me.

Why are we raising maximum entropy distribution probabilities to the power of policy probabilities?